# Matrix Monitoring Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I don't find any articles or docs describing how we can monitor superset in production environment. So any help regarding how we can have matrix which we can be use to monitor superset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superset emits events via [statsd](https://github.com/statsd/statsd), which is described as:
"*A network daemon that runs on the Node.js platform and listens for statistics, like counters and timers, sent over UDP or TCP and sends aggregates to one or more pluggable backend services (e.g., Graphite).*"

More information here:
https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#statsd-logging